# Math Sequence help

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have a sequence: 
7.537803 
30.1512 
67.8402 
120.60 
... it keeps going infinitely. There seems to be no equation to it. I have noticed however, that the ratio between subsequent terms tends towards 1: 
3.999998408 
2.25 
1.777780726 
...etc 
Again, no equation to it. However, my problem here is that whilst the sequence of ratios converges to 1, this should mean that there should eventually be a point where the difference is negligible. However, using massive numbers, I get a negligible difference. Say I use 999,999 and 1,000,000 to calculate results, but then at 999,999,999 and 1,000,000,000 the difference between the results gotten using each number is negligible but the difference between the result for 1,000,000,000 and that for 1,000,000 is quite a lot. If the ratio between subsequent terms converges to 1, and its pretty close to 1 when I use 1,000,000 and 999,999 to calculate a result, shouldnt the results calculated for 999,999,999 and 1,000,000,000 be far closer to that found for 999,999 and 1,000,000 (I say that instead of those because really the difference was very negligible).

Secondly, if I want to say that an equation for a term of another sequence is the previous term+15 how would i write it in mathematical notation? 
Thanks!
Update: Also, here's background info if you think it might be helpful. 
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qxmzxx...
Update 2: also-sorry just in case not clear: the difference between 999,999 and 1,000,000 and that between 999,999,999 and 1,000,000,000 was negligible my concern is with the difference between the two groups of numbers if that makes sense

Comment: The term ratio is $2^2/1^2, 3^2/2^2, 4^2/3^2, \ldots$

Comment: One issue I think you are having here is that the computer cannot represent non-integer numbers with complete accuracy. So when you do calculations involving sufficiently high numbers, the inaccuracy gets amplified. This may explain why you got worse results for the larger numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: The term ratio appears to be $\frac{2^2}{1^2}, \frac{3^2}{2^2}, \frac{4^2}{3^2}, \ldots$. So you can imagine, each term is a multiple of the first term, where the multiplier is $n^2$:

$$a_n = a_1n^2 \approx 7.537803 n^2$$

The term **difference**, $a_{n+1}-a_n$, is
$$\begin{align*}a_{n+1}-a_n
&= a_1[(n+1)^2-n^2]\\
&= a_1(2n+1)\\
&\to \infty
\end{align*}$$

which means the term difference is actually increasing and diverges.

The term **ratio**, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, on the other hand, is
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{a_1(n+1)^2}{a_1n^2}\\
&=\frac{n^2+2n+1}{n^2}\\
&= 1+\frac{2n+1}{n^2}\\
&\to 1
\end{align*}$$
which, as you expect, tends to $1$.

Comment: but if the ratio between terms is 1 wouldnt the terms be the same?

Comment: The ratio between terms tends to one. It is never exactly $1$.

Comment: ah I see I'm just surprised that the difference is so large though to be fair I am using massive numbers thanks so much!

Comment: also how did you guys get the term ratio?

Comment: @Alan By observation :), you can try writing $3.\dot9, 2.25, 1.\dot7$ as fractions. But I have to warn, all the above calculations are based on this observed pattern, so if your sequence turns out to be different, then all these may not apply.

Comment: ah thank you! btw it holds perfectly I've tested it with random small and large numbers. Thank you all so much for your help is there any way to give points or something on this site?

Comment: @Alan You can upvote answers and mark one answer as the correct answer. By doing so, this also helps others who may come to this question page one day.

Comment: alright will do hahah. Just so you all know, you guys just helped me in finding the equation for the approximate(because i didnt go to all sig figs) minimum surface area achievable by a soap film catenoid before it collapses at any radius (n would be the radius). Thanks!

Comment: @alan If the sequence is about surface area, then term ratio should follow the square of radius ratio, like what I observed from your original question.

Comment: and it does I believe doesn't it? Does this verify that my values for surface area (I initially obtained them using integration to find the surface of revolution)?

Comment: That depends on whether the solids with different radii are similar figures; if so, my answer might be a confirmation to your results.

Comment: they are all catenoids yes :D :D

Answer (score 0):

To your second question: $a_n= a_{n-1}+15$